# Does mongoDB supports sharding and replicaset on hybrid env (IBM8 and Intel server )

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to deploy MongoDB sharding and replica set on cross-platform hardware (hybrid) for instance?

Shard-1 on IBM power 8
Shard-2 on Intel or AMD processor

Answer (score 0):

In short YES. Each shard in MongoDB has its own mongod.